# Python Scraping from URL List

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am planning to open a CSV file containing a number of URLs I want to scrape. However, when running the request, I am only receiving a blank document as result. When entering the URLs directly into the Python code, things work well.

My thought is that something could be wrong with the CSV file as the code seems to be in line with what has worked for other users.

The CSV file, which is saved in the same folder as the scraper, is currently formatted as follows:

`'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=nws',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2017%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2017&tbm=nws',`

Does anyone have an idea what you be the reason for the blank document I am receiving? Please also find below the Python code I am using:

```
import scrapy

class TermSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'TermCheck'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']

with open('urls.csv') as file:
    start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'search_title': response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get(),
            'results': response.css('#resultStats::text').get(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
        yield item
```

Please find below the run trace:

```
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.0.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.5, Platform Darwin-18.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'quote7.csv', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 9e547af3b30153c7
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET 'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
  defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 70, in download_request
(scheme, self._notconfigured[scheme]))
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET 'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=nws'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
 defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 70, in download_request
(scheme, self._notconfigured[scheme]))
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET 'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2017%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2017&tbm=nws'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
 return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 70, in download_request
(scheme, self._notconfigured[scheme]))
 scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 966,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 15, 30, 19, 829530),
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'memusage/max': 50180096,
 'memusage/startup': 50180096,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 11, 15, 30, 19, 485355)}
2019-02-11 15:30:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check indents in your class or refactor file reading to:

```
import scrapy

class TermSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'TermCheck'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('urls.csv') as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                yield scrapy.Request(line.strip())

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'search_title': response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get(),
            'results': response.css('#resultStats::text').get(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
        yield item
```

Also please check your csv file and remove quotes and commas.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried that approach. It is still returning a blank document, however.

Comment: Can you add trace of your run to the original post? What do you mean by blank document?

Comment: Just a quick hint to make things easier for you: Use Pythons CSV module in order to read a CSV file without having to worry too much about the CSV-specifics: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I have just added the run trace to the original question

Comment: "Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme" -- check data in you csv. Remove quotes and commas, strip hidden symbols. Check what do you read from file.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed both and am still getting the same "Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme" info

Comment: Ok, great. Try to print `line` variable before calling request to it? Maybe encoding is broken or something alike?

Comment: Have added `print (line.strip())` and tried all possible CSV data constellations - with breaks/without breaks, with commas/without commas etc. None of these worked...

Comment: I am getting the following trace on this basis:

Comment: @M.S. Based on your trace you still have quotes in your input file. You need to remove ALL quotes.

Comment: @M.S. If your trace shows `<GET 'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws'>` then you still have single quotes in your file. It must show up as `<GET https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2017%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2017&tbm=nws>`. Note there are no single quotes in there.

Comment: I have done that - there are no quotes left in the CSV

Comment: Oh that was the trace I have added at an earlier stage of the discussion. I have removed them in the meantime

Comment: Receiving the following trace now (having removed the quotes in the CSV): `2019-02-11 15:53:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws'`
(shortened due to character limitation)
`2019-02-11 15:53:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET 'https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws'>`

Comment: No, you still have quotes in file: look, you have in trace `<GET -->'<--https...`

Comment: I can guarantee there are no quotes in the URL file. I have once again set up everything from scratch and the trace `<GET -->'<--https...`is still appearing

Comment: @M.S. Check if you have another `urls.csv` file in your project in a different folder. When you run `scrapy crawl` it is going to pick the file in the *current* directory. Make sure you have only one file and that you are editing the correct one.

Comment: @M.S. Otherwise you'll have to upload your project to GitHub so we can have a look.

Comment: Already done by linking the code to a new file name urls1.csv and saving the "correct" url list under this name

Comment: That would be great. I have uploaded the two files to https://github.com/shaping2startups/TermSpider

Comment: @M.S. Your CSV file still contains commas. You need to remove all commas. And put **one** URL per **line**.

Comment: I have just tried that (tried this modification before as well). It is still yielding a blank sheet...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188228/discussion-between-malberts-and-m-s).